# How can "generic" (not "express") PayPal checkout be implemented?

Tags: paypal, payment, checkout

[This page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) explains how "express" checkout can be implemented. It looks like the user is forced into entering his street address and lots of other data so that this data is later used for shipping.

The page briefly mentions "generic" checkout to which "express" checkout is opposed. Where can I get more information (preferably with examples) on how "generic" checkout can be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Express Checkout does not require users to input anything. That's the whole point of PayPal payments and where the term "express" comes from.  You just click the PayPal button, sign in, and agree to pay.  Your shipping address comes from what you already have entered in your PayPal account.

As for "generic" PayPal that would be [Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/).  You can use their basic HTML buttons or you if you're building in to your own shopping cart you can use the [cart upload method](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/).

If you are comfortable with web service API's, though, I would definitely recommend going with Express Checkout.  The experience for the buyer is very similar, but EC provides a lot more flexibility and features.

Comment: Is there any way to make Paypal show the page that doesn't require the phone number and street address? We're an online service and we don't ship - all we need is to get money charged from the customer and PayPal confirming that.

Comment: Express Checkout wouldn't do that by default.  All you should see is the login page unless you have some stuff specifically setup for Guest Checkout.  Some people prefer to show the credit card form on the EC pages by default instead of the basic login, so maybe that's what you saw..??  Do you have a screenshot of what you're talking about?

Comment: I asked a separate question with screenshots http://stackoverflow.com/q/24731409/57428