# How can I limit the set of fields Paypal shows on express checkout?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

Whenever our service initiates an express checkout and redirects the user to PayPal page the user sees the cart on the left and the following on the right:

[image: Payment form USA]

Note that even the address and the phone number are required while we're an online service and don't need shipping information - once PayPal confirms the payment we'll happily "ship" over the Internet, so all we really need is a PayPal payment confirmation and I guess that requires just a credit card number, expiration date and the CSC.

Yes, I know that users who have already registered with PayPal can switch to "my PayPal account" option but that doesn't help people who don't have a PayPal account and those are forced to see this page with 12 fields.

Wait, that was the form for people who have their "country" identified as the USA. Here's what people tracked to Colombia see:

[image: Payment from Colombia]

Even more fields and we only need a payment confirmation.

Is it possible to make PayPal limit the set of fields on that page?

Comment: The sandbox seems to be down right now, so I can't test this specifically, but have you tried setting NOSHIPPING=1 in your SetExpressCheckout request?  I know that eliminates shipping options in the PayPal side, but I've never tested if it eliminates the long form for Guest Checkout.  It may not, since when using a credit card like that PayPal wants to check the address verification.

Comment: @AndrewAngell: Okay, we tested it and it doesn't really help - looks like the address form is for billing address, not shipping address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can avoid user to enter Billing and Contact information on guest checkout only if you properly transmit **REAL** shipping/contact data by your own in your SetExpressCheckout call.

```
&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout 
&RETURNURL=https://...
&CANCELURL=https://...
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=10.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET=1 Main Street
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY=San Jose
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE=CA
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=US
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP=95131
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_EMAIL=jsmith01@example.com
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM=408-559-5948
```

If you set random data above with invalid city/state/zip PayPal will display Billing and Contact information inputs.